# Error WCF + AJAX call (XML Http Request Exception 101

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get an array with a ajax call to visualize this on my mainpage. I am using the Visual studio development server with port 4926. I am retrieving my data from my local WAMP server. I can fill my array with the required objects. But when i return this array, i get a error in my Ajax Function.

My Ajax Code:

```
getLastTenArticles: function () {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "../Magazine/Magazine.svc/GetLastTenArticles",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
```

}

My WCF Interface Method:

```
[OperationContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Article))]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Article[] GetLastTenArticles();
```

My Login and getting my user data works and this doesn't. I googled for a day, but haven't come across any solutions :(

Any help is appreciated :)